# Windows Phone epub reader

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, epub

I'm trying to build a wp7 application that must allow user to read ebooks in epub format. Since there isn't any available library to read epub file on a windows phone, I'm trying to create one. So I must unzip the file and then parse it.
The problem is that I can't unzip the epub file. I'm using `SharpZipLib.WindowsPhone7.dll` but I get an exception:

> Attempt to access the method failed: System.IO.File.OpenRead(System.String)

on this line:

```
ZipInputStream s = new ZipInputStream(File.OpenRead(path_epubfile));
```

Can any one help me, please?

Comment: What is `path_epubfile`? Is it contained in IsolatedStorage (ie. Built into the project as content, or downloaded from the web within your application) or is it embedded in your application? (Resource) ?

Comment: for the moment (to test the method) it is embedded in my application, but It will be contained in IsolatedStorage.

Comment: And what's the value of `path_epubfile`?

Comment: the value of path_epubfile is "/lapeste.epub". thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

It's going to depend on how the content is obtained. There's three possible options here;

**Option 1**: If the content is added to your project with a Build Action of "Content" you can obtain a stream by using the `StreamResourceInfo` class (In the `System.Windows.Resources` namespace)

```
  StreamResourceInfo info = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("MyContent.txt", UriKind.Relative));
  using (info.Stream) {
    // Make use of the stream as you will
  }
```

**Option 2**: If you've added it to your project and set the Build Action to "Embedded Resource" then you'll need to use `GetManifestResourceStream()`

```
using (Stream stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("ProjectName.MyContent.txt")) {
  // Make use of stream as you will
}
```

Note: You'll need to replace "ProjectName" with the name of your project. So if your project was "EPubReader" and the embedded resource was "Example.txt" you'd need to pass "EPubReader.Example.txt" to `GetManifestResourceStream()`. You can use `GetManifestResourceNames()` to see what resources are available.

**Option 3**: If you've obtained the content at run time, it'll be stored in `IsolatedStorage`.

```
using (IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()) {
  using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = store.OpenFile("MyContent.txt", FileMode.Open)) {
    // Make use of stream as you will
  }
}
```